# Django добавляет «index» в пустой URL

Tags: python, django

Я — новичок в Django. Не могу понять, почему в пустой URL добавляется «index».  Мне нужно, чтобы адрес был http://127.0.0.1:8000/, но Django сразу меняет на http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: у вас новый проект или вы чей то рассматриваете?

Comment: Я думаю тут проблема в локальном сервере. Если ввожу http://localhost:8000/, то "index" не подставляется

Comment: "у вас новый проект или вы чей то рассматриваете? – 5c0rp" Это новый проект

Answer (score 0):

Решение было очень простое, нужно было очистить кэш браузера :)